# Is there a way to check whether an option is valid for a certain program?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, `cat` doesn't have an option `'-a'`

When I try to run `cat -a`, I get the error message and usage line. Can I somehow get a truth value instead?

or do I have to do something like:

```
MESS=$(cat -a)
ERROR='illegal option -- a
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]'

if [ "$MESS" = "$ERROR" ] ; then
....
```

(although that doesn't work, it still prints the message to the screen instead of storing it to MESS)

Comment: Redirect stderr as well: `MESS=$(cat -a 2>&1)`

Comment: So I did that, but [ "$MESS" = "$ERROR" ] returns false..    But anyways this is a bad idea, because I'm not sure what illegal option the user will enter, so I won't know the exact error message.

Comment: Just check for `$?` after command execution

Comment: In general, no. You need to consult the program's documentation. A program doesn't have to do *anything* with an unsupported option; it could silently ignore it. In your example, you need to first redirect standard error to standard output in order to capture it: `MESS=$(cat -a 2>&1)`.

Answer (score 2):

you can see that certain program manual to see available options  for ex.

```
man cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix programs have a lot of flexibility in parsing command-line options, and the list of recognised options are not exposed in a machine-readable form. A perverse program could even vary its recognised options from run to run. At best, you are going to have to use heuristics based on parsing man pages and error output, but this is going to be quite error-prone.

However, all is not lost. [The fish(1) shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) has a lot of magic in it to guess likely-looking options for tab-completion, and you could inspect its code to see how it's done.